# Табы , и их переключение на событие скролла

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Входные данные :

1. ul > li (табы)
2. Скрипт который добавляет класс активный на клик по ul > li
3. ul ширина 300px высота 500px

Нужно на выходе :
 - При положении курсора в области данной ul , и использование скролла на мыше , переключались табы.(сама сложность , как заставить при положении мышки внутри блока хотя и скролле на мышки , хотя бы выводить console.log(), тк листает глобальное окно)

```js
(function($) {
  function consctructTabs(allButton, holderDivs) {
    var buttons = allButton,
      Divs = holderDivs;

    return $(buttons).click(function(elem) {
      $(Divs).removeClass('ActiveTab');
      $(buttons).removeClass('ActiveButtonTab');
      for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        if (elem.target == buttons[i]) {
          $(elem.target).addClass('ActiveButtonTab');
          $(Divs[i]).addClass('ActiveTab');
        }
      }
    })
  }

  // TABS-CLIENTS
  consctructTabs($('.clients-tab-nav li'), $('.realisation-right div'));
  //___________________________________


})(jQuery);
```

```css
.realisation-right div {
  display: none;
}

.realisation-right .ActiveTab {
  display: block;
}

.clients-tab-nav li {
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  margin:0 0 20px 0;
  color: #fff;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="clients-tab-nav">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="ActiveButtonTab">2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<div class="realisation-right">
  <div>11</div>
  <div>22</div>
  <div>33</div>
  <div>44</div>
  <div>55</div>

</div>
```

[Пример кода](https://jsfiddle.net/qmxb2g9x/)

Comment: хотя бы на https://jsfiddle.net/ накидайте макет, чтобы было с чем работать.

Comment: событие wheel  пробовали? https://learn.javascript.ru/mousewheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой пример. На событии wheel
https://jsfiddle.net/6okkLg5m/

```
var elem = $('.clients-tab-nav')[0];
if (elem.addEventListener) {
  if ('onwheel' in document) {
    // IE9+, FF17+, Ch31+
    elem.addEventListener("wheel", onWheel);
  } else if ('onmousewheel' in document) {
    // устаревший вариант события
    elem.addEventListener("mousewheel", onWheel);
  } else {
    // Firefox < 17
    elem.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", onWheel);
  }
} else { // IE8-
  elem.attachEvent("onmousewheel", onWheel);
}

function onWheel(e) {
  e = e || window.event;

  // wheelDelta не дает возможность узнать количество пикселей
  var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;

  var info = document.getElementById('delta');

  info.innerHTML = +info.innerHTML + delta;

  e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue = false);
}
```